# Add a property to every object in a json array in sql sever

Tags: json, sql-server

I need to add "Description" property with "" value to all items in my json array.

I have tried :

```
JSON_MODIFY(ReasonCodes, '$[0].Description', '')
```

and getting result as:

```
[
  {"Name":"jhfghgh","Code":"89798","Note":"dfgbcbxcbx","Description":""},
  {"Name":"test7889","Code":"9787","Note":""}
]
```

basically i want that properties should be also in 2nd or any number of array as well of that json object.

Comment: Having to modify individual properties is a **very** strong indication you should be using a separate ReasonCodes table instead of JSON strings

Comment: Yes, I have that also but this is another requirement that need to be handled

Comment: I am trying to execute this query:

Update PD
Set ReasonCodes = 
CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY(ReasonCodes, '$.Description', ''), ','), ']') 

and getting the error:

An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

The function `JSON_MODIFY()` doesn't support wild cards for value of the `path` parameter, so if the input JSON has a variable structure, you may try to parse the `ReasonCodes` JSON array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema, modify each item and aggregate the rows to build the final ouptut:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PD (ReasonCodes varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO PD (ReasonCodes)
VALUES ('[
   {"Name":"test1","Code":"0001","Note":"dfgbcbxcbx","Description":null},
   {"Name":"test2","Code":"0002","Note":"dfgbcbxcbx","Description":"ABCD"},
   {"Name":"test3","Code":"0003","Note":""}
]')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE PD 
SET ReasonCodes = CONCAT(
   '[', 
   (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.Description', ''), ',')
   FROM OPENJSON(ReasonCodes)
   ),
   ']'
)
```

If you need to change the `$.Description` key, but only when the keys exists, you need a different statement:

```
UPDATE PD 
SET ReasonCodes = CONCAT(
   '[', 
   (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(
      CASE
         WHEN j2.DescriptionCount > 0 THEN JSON_MODIFY(j1.[value], '$.Description', '')
         ELSE JSON_QUERY(j1.[value])
      END, 
      ','
   )
   FROM OPENJSON(ReasonCodes) j1
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM OPENJSON(j1.[value])
      WHERE [key] = 'Description'
   ) j2 (DescriptionCount)
   ),
   ']'
)
```

Comment: **I have tried the above solution as:**

UPDATE PD
SET ReasonCodes = CONCAT(
   '[', 
   (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.Description', ''), ',')
   FROM OPENJSON(ReasonCodes)
   ),
   ']'
) where ReasonCodes <>'' AND ReasonCodes <>'[]' and ISJSON(ReasonCodes)=1

**and its meeting my requirements but one more checks want to add in where condition if any "Description" property found in that json object array then do not update that. Please suggest any answer for this.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer it have fulfilled my criteria. except one more above additional checks needs to have in that query.